# Prestashop: how to replace Fancybox with Colorbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, colorbox, prestashop

Prestashop: how to replace Fancybox with Colorbox as large image viewer on the Product page? (when click the View Full Size link)

Comment: Check this http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/101924-tip-colorbox-to-replace-thickbox/ for instructions of how to install colorbox as your default lightbox in pretashop

Answer (score 2):

For prestashop 1.5 go to product controller on line 95 remove the fancybox option and include the colorbox.
$this->addJqueryPlugin(array('idTabs', 'scrollTo', 'serialScroll'));

Comment: It would be interesting to know how to fully replace Fancybox with Colorbox in Prestashop 1.5.3 (there is about 24 files that contain references to Fancybox.)